# Difference @GET @POST in REST architecture

Tags: rest, gwtp

I am trying to understand the REST architecture, but I have a question.

I do not understand all the differences, between @POST and @GET...for me, I just see them in a technical point of view, where my framework (GWT-P) allows me to use various parameter (String, int, but not objects) with @GET and various parameters (including ONLY ONE object class) with @POST...

So, what kind of error (logical error, bad architecture etc...) could I create, if I am using a @POST instead of @GET ? Because, for example, if I want to retrieve data, it seems logical to use @GET, isn t it ? But, if I want to pass a lot of parameters usefull to retrieve theses data (eg: the day, the place, the user...), so **technically**, I have to use @POST...

So, @GET, @POST ? Is it strictly necessary to respect the logic that all 'retrieve operations' (I mean fetching data operations) should be @GET and never @POST ?

Thansk you,

Comment: *Strictly* necessary?  No.  But if you need to pass a full object as an identifier to a REST service, you've probably missed the point of REST.

Comment: If you're concerned at all with the semantics of the URI, then you missed the point of REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, REST is an architectural style, so it's protocol independent. Your question is more related to the proper usage of HTTP than REST.

If you need to pass parameters on your retrieval, you should send them in the query string, not in a POST. Keep in mind that the whole URI, including the query string, is an atomic identifier to your resource.

The problem with retrieving with POST is that this method is reserved for non-idempotent operations, that might have some side-effect on the server side. For instance, a POST is never cached, and a client can't resubmit a POST at will if the response is lost without first checking if the request actually succeeded.

Comment: " is an atomic identifier to your resource" But I do not want to retrieve 1 resource, I retrieve various ones (I need to retrieve all the events occuring today for eg.). So, is it true that an URI can represent various resourceS ?

Comment: Is an atomic identifier in the sense that an URI is indivisible for REST. The whole URI points to a resource. Period. In your case, that resource can be a collection of links pointing to other resources. No problem with that. What you can't do is return two different representations of different resources on separated calls to the same URI.

Comment: If you need to retrieve all events for today, you can do GET /events/today, or GET /events/2013/11/02, or GET /events?date=2013-11-02. All of these are valid. The semantics of the URI are irrelevant for REST, because the client is supposed to get to this by following a "today" link or something like that given by the parent resource.

Answer (score 1):

Basically these HTTP methods are just semantics and their intended usage is just a guideline.

However, when handling these requests server-side remember, that web crawlers also use these methods, so, for example, making GET requests do anything besides just displaying data is unsafe and may produce some hard-to-track problems with your app.

A bit more on this.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods

Comment: I do not understand what are theses sides effects they are always talking about...Could you give me one example ?  I also have read that the server should always be STATELESS, is that true ?

Answer (score 0):

In the REST logic :

- GET => to get a resource (with an id)
- POST => to create a resource
- PUT => to update a resource (with an id)
- DELETE => to remove a resource (with an id)

It's rarely necessary to specify many parameters for a resource (otherwise, there's a problem 
in the software design).

Normally only an identifier as a parameter (or an identifier and a type of resource, a libel, ..., but no exceed the limit number of parameters in HTTP/GET).

Comment: I think that's not what is asked.

Comment: I 'know it'...I can use (it compiles and works) @ POST in order to get a resource. It does not seems logic, but I have to use @ POST in order to pass an 'object' parameter...My question is: "if it I use @ POST instead of @ GET in order to get a ressource, what kind of error could happen" ?

Comment: @АндрейПочекуев : Hum, I was trying to complete my answer and I think that's not off topic ;)

Comment: In REST, the id for a resource is the whole URI, so it doesn't make sense to think of parameters and id as different things. From a RESTful standpoint, it doesn't matter if the URI has an ID, querystring parameters or anything else.

Comment: @PedroWerneck I moderately agree. Yes we often designate a URI when we talk about a ressource id in Rest.

But when I was talking about "id", I was talking about a value which allow the REST service to find the corresponding resource in the storage medium used (database, ...). Example of URI :

<host>/<name_of_rest_service>/<version?>/<value_which_allows_us_to_identify_the_ressource>/<type_of_resource?>

Then I totally agree with that : "a URI normally allows to identify a single resource".

Comment: That's an issue of HTTP and your implementation, not directly related to REST. The REST service finds the corresponding resource by the URI, as an atomic entity. How the implementations breaks the URI to find the object in storage is not related to REST at all. If you're building URI's from patterns as you show, then you're not using HATEOAS, and you're not doing REST at all.

Comment: @nzaero Why do you have to pass an entire object to POST, if you're just getting information?  Why can't you just pass the ID of that object?

Comment: @Aaron: The ID is not enought, because the query to the database will be done on the server side. And for this query, I do not know the ID, but I know that I want all the event of a given : date, country, user. And I have all theses parameters in an object that I can just pass with @ POST.

Answer (score 0):

If your publishing an API for this then I would use @GET methods, but if that is not the case use @POST by all means.

@POST gives you more options and dosn't have a limit on parameter query string length like @GET, the only negative is @POST is slower by a couple of milliseconds to create the request.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass query information to a URI to specify exactly what resource you want don't use a POST. Use a GET with a *query string*.

For example

```
http://myapi.com/someresource?day=01012014&place=Dublin&user=JohnDoe
```

or if there is a meaningful hierarchy then build it into the URI itself

```
http://myapi.com/users/JohnDoe/locations/Dublin/telephones/01231414
```